# How do I make an interactive video where an object's data displays on the screen when a user clicks the object?

Tags: reactjs, video-streaming, mern, google-vision, clickable

I'm trying to display object data on a video when a user clicks on the object in the video but having some difficulty. I'm using a MERN stack in addition to Google Vision API and have the data in my MongoDB and can GET the data via Postman but when I click on the object in the browser a fetch request isn't made, nothing happens. I was thinking that I'm going to have to get the position of the object in each frame and make the necessary correspondences but I'm not too sure. Can't seem to figure it out so if anyone has suggestions I'd be happy to hear them!

Thanks!

Client

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function VideoPlayer() {
  const [objects, setObjects] = useState([]);
  const [selectedObject, setSelectedObject] = useState(null);
  const [videoUrl, setVideoUrl] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  // Fetch object data when an object is clicked
  function fetchObjectData(objectId) {
    // Set loading state while fetching
    setIsLoading(true);

    // Fetch detected object data for the specific object
    fetch(`http://localhost:3001/annotation/${objectId}`)
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
        }
        return response.json(); // Assuming the response contains JSON data
      })
      .then(data => {
        setSelectedObject(data); // Update selectedObject with the fetched data
        setIsLoading(false); // Clear loading state
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching object data:', error);
        setIsLoading(false); // Clear loading state on error
      });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch video URL from the backend
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/videourl')
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
        }
        const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
        if (contentType && contentType.startsWith('video')) {
          return response.blob();
        } else {
          console.error('Unexpected response type:', contentType);
          setError(new Error('Unexpected response type'));
        }
      })
      .then(videoBlob => {
        setVideoUrl(URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error fetching video URL:', error);
        setError(error);
      });
      
  }, []);

  function handleObjectClick(objectId) {
    console.log('Clicked object ID:', objectId);
    // Clear selectedObject when a new object is clicked
    setSelectedObject(null);
    // Fetch object data when an object is clicked
    fetchObjectData(objectId);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {error ? (
        <div>Error: {error.message}</div>
      ) : (
        <>
          <video
            src={videoUrl}
            muted
            autoPlay
            playsInline
            loop
            style={{ width: '100%', height: '300pt' }}
          />
          <div className="annotationsContainer">
            {isLoading ? (
              <div>Loading data...</div>
            ) : (
              objects.map((object, index) => (
                <div
                  key={index}
                  className="annotation"
                  onClick={() => handleObjectClick(object.id)}
                >
                  <strong>{object.entity.description}</strong>
                  <br />
                  Confidence: {object.confidence}
                </div>
              ))
            )}
          </div>
          {selectedObject && (
            <div className="selectedObject">
              <strong>Selected Object:</strong> {selectedObject.entity.description}
              <br />
              Confidence: {selectedObject.confidence}
            </div>
          )}
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default VideoPlayer;
```

Server and Route

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const {ObjectModel} = require('../../model/index');


router.get('/:objectId', async (req, res) => {
  const objectId = req.params.objectId;

  try {
    // Use the objectId to retrieve the specific object from the database
    const object = await ObjectModel.findById(objectId);
    if (!object) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Object not found' });
    }

    res.json(object);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching object:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});

module.exports = router;

const router = require('express').Router();
const annotationRoutes = require('./api/annotationroute');
const videoURLRoutes = require('./api/videourlroute');

router.use('/annotation', annotationRoutes);
router.use('/videourl', videoURLRoutes);

router.use((req, res) => {
  return res.send('Wrong route!');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Model

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const objectSchema = new Schema({

    objectDescription: {
        type: String,  
    },
    objectEntityId: {
        type: String,
    },
    objectStartTime: {
        type: String,
    },
    objectEndTime: {
        type: String,
    },
    objectConfidence: {
        type: Number,
    },
   
});

const ObjectModel = model('Object', objectSchema);

module.exports = ObjectModel;
```

I've tried making various console.logs but I'm not getting any errors and the Network tab isn't telling me anything either- fetch request aren't being made. I've tried searching for Google vision API demos for making clickable videos on Youtube as well as searched documentation but nothing's turned up.

Comment: Does it work if you replace quotes in  `fetch(`http://localhost:3001/annotation/${objectId}`)` with different quote marks like:  `fetch('http://localhost:3001/annotation/${objectId}')`? As you can see, your original code cannot be even be parsed correctly because of the wrong quote marks within the command. Does React needs them to be like that?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I'm not sure what you mean...I'm fairly confident I have quote marks where they should be and if this were incorrect the error would be made known in vs code.

Comment: Well, to clarify, I'm using backticks and not quotes which is necessary for ObjectID to be read.

Comment: **For the record** (your comment in the currently deleted Answer): _"I'm currently exploring another solution which overlays a canvas on top of the video so that when a user clicks on the canvas, the coordinates of that position are sent to the db and if there's an object at that position then data about that object is sent back. However, the issue I foresee with this is that the canvas wouldn't be updating in real time and, therefore, not in sync with the video so I'll have to identify work arounds. Anyway, if you have other suggestions I'd be happy to try them out. **– 
Nicholas Ortiz**"_

Comment: Okay so the Fetch request was just a side issue? Your main problem is object tracking through frames? If yes, then please show an example video of some typical content. The approach to a solution (where searching per frame) could depend on anything from: (1) **Colour palette**, if there is a specific block's colour pattern or fill that can be followed? (2) **Frame differencing**, if the camera doesn't move? (3) **Area search in greyscale or Posterized colour mode**, if assuming no fast movement, the same colour shades (clicked object) should exist as shifted by a few pixels within a same area.

Comment: **PS:** You need to show an example video because it's not clear about the quality & category of your input video. Maybe you have conveyor belt footage (_eg:_ track by speed & direction) or else it is some street CCTV. Tracking a box of cornflakes moving sideways has a different solution from tracking an ice-skater doing competition tricks. **PPS:** You need to ask a new Question about object tracking on canvas. Right now **your shown code and your Title do not match**. Does fixing the Fetch request solve your problem? If yes, why is it not _"How to fix my Fetch request?"_ to attract Answers?

Comment: Well, no, the fetch request is a symptom of the issue which is that when a user sees an object of interest in a video and clicks on the object, a fetch request to retrieve information about that object to be displayed on the browser is not made. The video is non-animated (for the most part, think of it as tracking materials in a storage space). There are several ways this can be done: 1. use Google Vision to identify assets in a video, store that data in a db and retrieve the data using the method earlier (in the deleted answer). This isn't included because there it's just hypothesis testing.

Comment: Method mentioned in previous answer: "I'm currently exploring another solution which overlays a canvas on top of the video so that when a user clicks on the canvas, the coordinates of that position are sent to the db and if there's an object at that position then data about that object is sent back. However, the issue I foresee with this is that the canvas wouldn't be updating in real time and, therefore, not in sync with the video so I'll have to identify work arounds. Anyway, if you have other suggestions I'd be happy to try them out."

Comment: Another method is to perform the object identification via Google Vision in realtime so that when a user clicks on the video, a fetch request is made to initiate the analysis subsequently providing information about the object of interest. This requires more development time but I might be exploring this soon.